# Explain behaviour terniary operator and default

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain the following behaviour?

I am trying to return null, as int?, if a int.TryParse return false.
From the following options, all return null except the second:

```cs
var resultInt1 = int.TryParse(null, out var result) ? result : (int?)default; //null
var resultInt2 = int.TryParse(null, out var result2) ? result2 : default; //0
var resultInt3 = int.TryParse(null, out var result3) ? result3 : (int?)null; //null
var resultInt4 = int.TryParse(null, out var result4) ? result4 : default(int?); //null
```

isn't default for int? null? Why is it returning 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional operator always has to select a best type from the types of the two possible results. In 3 of your samples, you're asking it to select between `int` and `int?` and it decides that `int?` is the best type.

However, when you have just `int` and `default`, `default` doesn't *have* a type and must be inferred from context. So the only possible type the compiler can choose as the type for the conditional is `int`. Having made that decision, it now knows that `default` is the same as `default(int)` which is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If the string to parse is null, Int32.TryParse will always return false, after setting the default value for the out parameter.
So you get always the false part of your expressions but all the out variables above are set to their default value.

Because Int32.TryParse expects the out variable to be an integer, then, if you look at the value set in the out variables you will see that are all set to 0.

You can see this behavior looking at the referencesource site following the source code of [Int32.TryParse](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,152)

Answer (score 1):

In the second case the type is `int`, not `int?`.

`int.TryParse` works with `int` not `int?` so it's the `else` part that dictates `int?` in the 1st, 3rd and 4th cases.

It becomes clearer if you 'unwind' the code.

```
//var resultInt1 = int.TryParse(null, out var result) ? result : (int?)default; //null
int result; // <--- int, not 'int?'
int? resultInt1; // has to be nullable 
if (int.TryParse(null, out result))
    resultInt1 = result;
else
    resultInt1 = (int?)default; //null

// var resultInt2 = int.TryParse(null, out var result2) ? result2 : default; //0
// is equivalent (note 'int', not 'int?'
// int resultInt2 = int.TryParse(null, out var result2) ? result2 : default; //0
// is equivalent
int result2; // <--- int, not 'int?'
int resultInt2; // <------------------- here, it's an int
if (int.TryParse(null, out result2))
    resultInt2 = result2;
else
    resultInt2 = default; <--‐------ the only case with an 'int', not an 'int?'
```

Comment: The point here is that `var resultIntX` is always derived to be an `int?`, except for the second case where the else section ALSO returns an non-nullable integer. And `default(int) = 0` and `default(int?) = null`.